# Clear remove of additional Python from usr/local/ on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, python

I need to use a machine at work (12.04 Ubuntu box) that has two versions of Python installed: the default 2.7.3 one from the /usr/bin and a 2.7.5 one that was installed into usr/local/bin. The isntallation wasn't clean, in the sense no alt-install was used and the `python` now redirects to the 2.7.5.

I don't know how long it was there or what kind of python-dependent tools have been installed after over it. The problem is that pip was installed only for the 2.7.3, but tries to install into the 2.7.5 folders, making compilation of numpy or scipy impossible.

What is the cleanest way of removing the 2.7.5 without breaking any dependencies or, in the worst case, redirecting them onto the 2.7.3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

to redirect python to 2.7.3  type in terminal

```
sudo update-alternatives --config python
```

and then select the version of python most likely 3

to remove pythn 2.7.5 use apt-get i.e

```
 sudo apt-get remove python2.7-5
```

then run

```
sudo  apt-get autoremove
```

to remove any dependancies not needed